# How to add compound index to table in mongodb after creating it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have created model and have few documents inserted but when I now add index, index is not working. I tried emptying the table using

```
db.orders.remove({})
```

but still index is not working with me being able to insert duplicate items. Following is my model in mongoose.

```
var OrderSchema = new Schema({
  client_order_id: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  client_request_id: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  created: {
    type : Date, 
    default: Date.now 
  },
  updated: {
    type : Date, 
    default: Date.now 
  },
});

OrderSchema.index({client_order_id:1, client_request_id:1}, { unique: true });
```

When I check the logs of mongodb in terminal I can see errors though it still accepts duplicates

```
2014-12-28T02:46:56.819+0530 [conn9]     building index in background
2014-12-28T02:46:56.820+0530 [conn9] background addExistingToIndex exception E11000 duplicate key error index: mean-dev.orders.$client_order_id_1  dup key: { : "141216629793885" }
2014-12-28T02:46:56.820+0530 [conn9] index build failed. spec: { v: 1, unique: true, key: { client_order_id: 1 }, name: "client_order_id_1", ns: "mean-dev.orders", background: true, safe: null } error: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: mean-dev.orders.$client_order_id_1  dup key: { : "141216629793885" }
```

Note:

It worked after I changed to

```
OrderSchema.index({client_order_id:1, client_request_id:1}, { unique: true, dropDups: true });
```

and deleted the table, restarted the mongodb server

Comment: Make sure you're dropping the `orders` collection from the right database in the shell.  Run `use mean-dev` first.

Comment: @JohnnyHK yes that was my mistake. do we have to restart the table everytime we change index?

Comment: You don't; but you do need to get rid of any duplicates before you add the unique index (or use the `dropDups` option when creating the index).

Comment: @raju: If you change your indices often, there is most likely something wrong with your data model. Indices typically don't change very often – at most as often as your data model does, which tends to happen early in the development process. Be careful – MongoDBs dynamic schema comes at the drawback that you need to be highly disciplined regarding your models – as strange as it sounds.